# How to accelerate the evaporation of water at temperature below 5 °C?

Tags: water, temperature, drying

How can we make the water to evaporate at low temperature? Does addition of high evaporating solvents help or decrease in the hydrogen bonding by addition of solute will help? Is there any other method to evaporate water at low temperature?

Comment: Related: [Is there a chemical that when added to water makes the water flash evaporate?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58907)

Comment: Without working at low pressure, water will evaporate quicker by bubbling it with a currant of dry air, whatever the temperature.

Answer (score 4):

**Low pressure is the way to go, adding other solvents doesn't help much**

There is only one (easy) way to get cold water to evaporate quickly. That is to lower the pressure. At a pressure of about 1% of atmospheric pressure (achievable with a standard laboratory water aspirated vacuum pump) water boils at about 10 celsius. Even water at 5 degrees celsius will evaporate quickly, especially in a system like a rotary evaporator that maximises the surface area of liquid.

A slightly better vacuum will reduce that to <5 celsius and your water will boil even faster.

Adding other solvents can create azeotropes that boil under normal conditions and atmospheric pressure below the normal boiling point of water, but not by much. And, of course, your water is now contaminated with another solvent.